# How to restrict to 1 year period

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, having

This query returns 3 years of records. How can I change it to return (the most recent) 1 year of records?

```
select id, format(ual.inserted, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as inserted
from ual
where id = 347877
group by id, format(ual.inserted, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
having format(ual.inserted, 'yyyy-MM-dd') >= dateadd(year,-1,max(inserted))
order by format(ual.inserted, 'yyyy-MM-dd') desc
```

What I'm trying to do is return the most recent 1 year of records for each `id`.

**EDIT** Change made after comment from @Squirrel:

```
select id, format(ual.inserted, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as inserted
from ual
where webid = 347877 and format(ual.inserted, 'yyyy-MM-dd') >= dateadd(year,-1,max(inserted))
order by format(ual.inserted, 'yyyy-MM-dd') desc
```

This query produces this error:

```
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
```

Comment: add the condition required to `WHERE` clause. Not `HAVING`. And why are you using `GROUP BY` when there isn't any aggregate function required

Comment: i've added the changed query to the post. this produces the noted error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use sub-query to find the `max` of `inserted` and then use it in `where`

```
select id, format(ual.inserted, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as inserted
from   ual
where id = 347877
and   ual.inserted >= (
                          select dateadd(year,-1,max(inserted))
                          from   ual x
                          where  x.id = ual.id
                      )
order by format(ual.inserted, 'yyyy-MM-dd') desc
```